# Npm install is not working getting bower ECMDERR

Tags: node.js, angularjs, meanjs

I am getting the bellow error while running

```
npm install
```

command

> bower ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
> [https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography.git"](https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography.git%22), exit code of
> #128 remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography.git/'

I tried to clear the

```
~/.gitconfig 
            [url "https:/"]
            insteadOf = git://
            [url "http://"]
            insteadOf = git://
```

and I did run this command as well

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

but nothing is working for me, below are the configuration details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04LTS
Project: Means JS (angularjs, nodejs, mongodb, express js)
node version: 8.17.0
npm version: 6.13.4
bower version: 1.8.8
need help in fixing the above issue
```